Is there a cheaper alternative to Liquid Color Standards?
I'm trying to create a sensor that measures the fluid color within a PVC tube that exits from a patient's surgical wound.
I have a handheld spectrophotometer and a TCS3200 sensor, and I'm trying to set the optimal LED intensity for it using a custom-made dark chamber.
While it makes sense to use the handheld spectrophotometer as a standard, I also would like to crosscheck it with some sort of standard fluid. But from what I've seen, lab-grade standard fluids are very expensive (100+ dollars for small vials), and I don't really need that precise measurement for the experiment I'm running. It just needs to be as accurate as or better a experienced surgeon for discerning which shade of yellow/red/green it is. Are there any commercial fluids that I can use to calibrate/cross-check this setup?
I'm looking for something simple like Coca-Cola or Fanta. Something that has a recipe that is almost universal and probably standard everywhere... Or I can mix up a solution that can be created from simple ingredients?

Just a warning on things being 'almost universal' from many moons ago. My family backpacked a lot, starting in the 1970s. At that point we would take powdered Tang to have 'orange juice' for breakfast. Well, we went to backpack across Corsica and picked up some powdered Tang there. Now, at the time, we used iodine to sanitize the water we drank. Did just fine in the US with Tang. On Corsica, the Tang turned a beautiful purple color in iodized water. Tasted just fine, but the color was not ideal. So, clearly Tang was not Tang.

Very interesting. However, I do have access to distilled water and may request access to both the university's pathology and biochemistry labs to get some dyes/powders, which should hopefully enable me to create a standard fluid of some sort. Or I could purchase commercially distilled water that they sell for car stuff (?) to mix with Tang. Oh, I remember we also have an old cuvette spectrophotometer in the biochemistry lab; I can also use that if that would help with my task.

Just to be clear, I was not advocating for Tang…

Yeah, I know :) Sorry, I was being obtuse.
